# stagger children framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, tailwind-css, framer-motion

am trying to stagger the details items but the parent vars doesn't seem to be working here I've tried editing the delay times
and tried changing the exit or the initial variants nothing seems to be working , tried adding divs as parents

tried moving the variants into the inner div

but when i edited the animations in  a way to show if it's taking effect on children it seems to be working so i think the problem is in timing

or what am I missing here?
thanks in advance

```
import { useState } from "react";
import CarouselP1 from "../carousel/carouselP1";
import { MdKeyboardDoubleArrowDown } from "react-icons/md";
import { MdKeyboardDoubleArrowUp } from "react-icons/md";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

const ProjectCard1 = ({ images }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handleExpand = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  const details = [
    {
      text: "afafcacascasc",
    },
    {
      text: "adasdascasc",
    },
    {
      text: "afafcacawfgwefaEDFAscasc",
    },
    {
      text: "afafcaE5TWERWEcascasc",
    },
    {
      text: "DFWEQFEAFA",
    },
    {
      text: "HRTHDGDRG",
    },
  ];
  const menuVars = {
    initial: {
      height: 0,
    },
    animate: {
      height: "15rem",
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
    exit: {
      height: 0,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };

  const parentVars = {
    initial: {
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.2,
        staggerDirection: -1,
      },
    },
    open: {
     
      transition: {
        delayChildren: 0.3,
        staggerChildren: 0.2,
        staggerDirection: 1,
      },
    },
  };

  const childVars = {
    initial: {
      y: "30vh",
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
    open: {
      y: 0,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.7,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-col space-y-3">
      <CarouselP1 images={images} />
      <div className=" flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-96 max-w-80">
        <p className=" ">WEGdrfbxcvb</p>
      </div>
      <button
        className="flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer"
        onClick={handleExpand}
      >
        <span className="pr-2">Details</span>
        {expanded ? (
          <MdKeyboardDoubleArrowUp className="mt-1" />
        ) : (
          <MdKeyboardDoubleArrowDown className="mt-1" />
        )}
      </button>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {expanded && (
          <motion.div
            variants={menuVars}
            initial="initial"
            animate="animate"
            exit="exit"
            className="flex rounded-lg items-center h-[15rem] justify-center w-48 bg-sky-200 my-2 origin-top"
          >
              <motion.div
                className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full"
                variants={parentVars}
                initial="initial"
                animate="open"
                exit="initial"
              >
                {details.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="overflow-hidden">
                      <motion.div
                       key={index}
                        variants={childVars}
                        initial="initial"
                        animate="open"
                      >
                        {item.text}
                      </motion.div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </motion.div>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>

      <button className="w-18 h-10 p-2 bg-sky-400 rounded-lg">
        <a href="">Source Code</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectCard1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `initial` and `animate` props from the children divs. [The framer motion docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/###staggerchildren) show the children not having those props, but they don't tell you why. My guess is that they override the animation variant transitions. [The `animate` and `initial` prop will propagate to the children](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/##propagation), so that may also be why. Here's a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stagger-children-framer-motion?file=app%2Fpage.tsx).

Comment: I've taken a different approach and mapped through the children  and added a delay time depending on the index of each child.